# Eclipse CDT - gdb watch expression

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, gdb, eclipse-cdt

I have been trying to use eclipse CDT to debug my C code. I see that unlike what gdb does, when a watch expression is added, the program does not break when the value changes(write). I also tried using "toggle breakpoints" from run option, it says "The option is unavailable." Is there something I am missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

What you need is `watchpoint`s instead of `watch expression`s.

Try Googling that. Usage varies with your specific Eclipse version.

Comment: Looks like eclipse CDT does not support watch-points on local variables. Thanks anyway.